# How can we copy two buffers both allocated by Marshal.AllocHGlobal?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, unsafe

There are ways in `Marshal` to copy raw buffer allocated by `AllocHGlobal` to/from C# array. But my question is, I have two buffers both allocated by `AllocHGlobal`, and I want to simply copy one buffer to another.

```
var buffer1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
var buffer2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
nativeOpOn(buffer1);
SomeCopy(buffer1, buffer2, size);
```

I know one possible solution is to P/Invoke system C lib for `memcpy`, but then I have to write different P/Invoke for support both Windows and Linux and MacOS, since they might have different P/Invoke stuff.

Comment: You could use an unsafe block and perform the copy using pointers. Or p/invoke. Or copy to and from a temp byte array but that sounds a little lame.

Comment: Thanks, the reason is, the buffer type is unknown, so I cannot specify a native pointer, I just want to do raw memory copy. Constructing a temp byte array introduces unnecessary memory copy.

Comment: If you can use an unsafe block, that's the easiest way to make it x-plat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using .Net 4.6 or later, you can use [`Buffer.MemoryCopy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.memorycopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
unsafe
{
    Buffer.MemoryCopy(p1.ToPointer(), p2.ToPointer(), destSizeBytes, sourceBytesToCopy);
}
```

Of course, it is `unsafe`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approaches:

1) managed buffer:

```
int size = sizeof(int); // for test purposes
IntPtr buffer1 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
IntPtr buffer2 = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

Marshal.WriteInt32(buffer1, 0x12345678); // native op (for test purposes)

byte[] bytes = new byte[size]; // managed buffer
Marshal.Copy(buffer1, bytes, 0, size); //buffer1=>bytes
Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, buffer2, size); //bytes=>buffer2
// use several iterations if needed

int res =  Marshal.ReadInt32(buffer2, 0); // for test purposes (res==0x12345678)
```

2) managed read/write operations via the `Marshal.ReadByte/WriteByte` methods or any `Marshal.ReadXXXe/WriteXXX` methods (depending of `size`). Just repeat these operations in cycle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    Marshal.WriteByte(buffer2, i, Marshal.ReadByte(buffer1, i));
```

3) unsafe block (read/write buffers via unsafe pointers)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running .NET Core or .NET 5+ then using the `Unsafe.CopyBlock()`/`Unsafe.CopyBlockUnaligned()` methods will be the fastest.

Running the following benchmarks using BenchmarkDotNet

```csharp
// .NET 6.0.300

[MemoryDiagnoser]
[RPlotExporter]
public unsafe class CopyTests
{
    private readonly void* source;
    private readonly void* destination;
    
    private const int SIZE = 1024;
    
    public CopyTests()
    {
        source = NativeMemory.Alloc(SIZE);
        destination = NativeMemory.Alloc(SIZE);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
    public void TestUnsafeCopyBlockUnaligned()
    {
        Unsafe.CopyBlockUnaligned(destination, source, SIZE);
    }

    [Benchmark]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining | MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]
    public void TestBufferMemoryCopy()
    {
        Buffer.MemoryCopy(source, destination, SIZE, SIZE);
    }
}
```

yields the following results:

```
|                       Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev | Allocated |
|----------------------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|----------:|
| TestUnsafeCopyBlockUnaligned | 16.63 ns | 0.350 ns | 0.360 ns |         - |
|         TestBufferMemoryCopy | 23.88 ns | 0.264 ns | 0.234 ns |         - |
```

or if you like pretty diagrams:

[image: diagram]

As you can see, `Unsafe.CopyBlockUnaligned()` is around 25% faster.

If you're using `IntPtr` you'd obviously have to call `myIntPtr.ToPointer()` first and also allow unsafe blocks in your project settings :)